# Enabling versioning on Digital Ocean Space via aws CLI. Command from docs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-ocean

I'm trying to enable versioning on my Digital Ocean bucket/space and am following these docs here: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/how-to/enable-versioning/

I have done: `aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket "my-assets" --endpoint="https://my-assets.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com" --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled`

and I'm getting `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`, which suggests that there is an argument not getting passed?! But I can't see an error in it (I've have shell-checked it)

I'm on ZSH and my aws cli version is `aws-cli/2.0.7 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/23.1.0 botocore/2.0.0dev11`

Any help greatly appreciated!